# Design Help Wanted: place the sensors near the arduino and remotely control the humidifier belt 20 ft away, or vice versa?

Tags: design

{This question first asked on Arduino Stack Exchange. Their complaint was that it didn't specifically pertain to Arduinos. Still needing my questions answered. See what you think. Open to suggestions best stack exchange to use, if this isn't it either. Thanks.}

I have started my first Arduino project! An old style belt driven humidifier needs a sensor for outside temperature and another sensor for current indoor humidity. I have a forced air furnace with two pipes going outside. one pipe pulls in air and the temperature sensor can go in there. The other pipe pushes out air from the furnace. It's not the burner stack pipe, but another pipe with normal breathable air (I think). The humidity sensor can go in this other pipe.

The two pipes are 20 feet from the humidifier unit.

Do I place the Arduino Uno R3 near the humidifier, or near the two sensors? I wish to turn the 24 VAC motor on the humidifier, to the "on" position, when indoor humidity and outside temperatures are below a common graph for humidifiers. The graph shows when you have enough humidity, for if you go over this amount, your windows will experience condensation, with droplets accumulating at the bottom of the window sills and rot the wood that is present there. Something to avoid.

I also wish to power the Arduino from 120V AC wall socket.

I have a SainSmart 2-Channel 4V Relay that indicates it should work with the much higher AC voltages and amperages. I need it to turn my 24 VAC motor on and off. I will need to confirm it's specs with you.

Thanks.

Comment: The reason the question isn't Arduino-specific is that you could replace the word "Arduino" with "controller" throughout without either the question or the answer changing. There is little about Arduinos that is special, other than their ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would place the Arduino close to the sensors as these are probably analog signals. The shorter the wire, the less chance on signal loss or disturbances.
2. Yes, you can easily power your Arduino from an AC socket via an USB adapter or an universal AC to DC (7-12V) adapter with barrel plug.
3. The relay seems ok for continuous operation, but I don't know how well it will hold up for the power surges when you try to turn the motor on or off. This will depend on the circuit that is already present in the motor.